# Assigning a variable to an earlier ListNode variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have code that works exactly how I want it to but I don't understand why Python is allowing for ListNode `x.next` to be changed when a separate ListNode `y` gets an update to its `y.next` value. see below code:

```
    class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
        
x = ListNode(1, None)
a = ListNode(2, None)
y = x
b = ListNode(5, None)

x.next = a
y.next = b

print(x.val)          >>>       1
print(x.next.val)     >>>       5        # how is this not 2 ???
```

This flies in the face of what I thought I knew about assigning multiple variables in Python. This seems to be the opposite of how Python handles multiple variables. Notice how in the below code, changing 'y' doesn't change what 'x' is:

```
x = 5
y = x

y += 1

print(y)      >>>    6
print(x)      >>>    5
```

Comment: `y = x` doesn't make `y` a copy of `x`, it makes `y` *another name for* `x`.  Afterwards, a mutation to `y` (such as `y.next = b`) will equally affect `x`, but assigning a new value to `y` breaks the connection.

Comment: `x` is an object so `y=x` means that `y` is that same object. likewise `x.next = a` means that `x.next = ListNode(2, None)` because `a = ListNode(2, None)`...  and the same for `b`, this is why... in fact in the debugger you can see the memory space allocated to each.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is an object so `y=x` means that `y` is that same object. likewise `x.next = a` means that `x.next = ListNode(2, None)` because `a = ListNode(2, None)`... and the same for `b`, this is why... in fact in the debugger you can see the memory space allocated to each.

Here is the debugger image to show this...

[image]